# What does c!='\n' do in a for statement?

Tags: c

I am a beginner and was learning to code using k&r's c programming book. Now there is this example of "a program to input set of text lines and print the longest"

I am giving you the whole code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define MAXLINE 1000

    int getline(char line[], int maxline);
    void copy(char to[], char from[]);

    int main()
    {
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];
    max=0;

    while((len=getline(line,MAXLINE))>0)
    if(len>max)
    {
    max=len;
    copy(longest,line);
    }
    if(max>0)
    printf("%s",longest);
    return 0;
    }

    int getline(char s[], int lim)
    {
    int c,i;
    for(i=0;i<lim-1&&(c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n';i++)
    s[i]=c;
    if(c=='\n')
    {
    s[i]='\n';
    i++;
    }
    s[i]='\0';
    return i;
    }

    void copy(char to[], char from[])
    {
    int i;
    i=0;
    while((to[i]=from[i])!='\0')
    i++;
    }
```

Now tell me, in getline function, in the statement:

```
    for(i=0;i<lim-1&&(c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n';i++)
```

why do we use " c!='\n' "

and what is the meaning of code after this `for` statement i.e.

```
     s[i]=c;
     if(c=='\n)
     {
     s[i]=c;
     i++;
     }
     s[i]='\0'
```

why have we used s[i]='\0' in this?

and `i++;` statement in `if(c=='\n')` condition?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention.

Comment: You are certain that these concepts aren't explained in the book already?

Comment: yes mr. bart and there isn't even any video

Comment: One of the first pages of the book will explain the '\n' I'm certain

Comment: mr michael maybe thats becoz of typing mistake..i am using stack overflow for the first time

Comment: @yogirajput you can edit your question and improve it.

Comment: mr bart :) i know '\n stands for new line but i didn't get this code at all

Comment: mr michael okk i am editing it

Comment: @yogirajput `for(i=0;i<lim-1&&(c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n';i++)` the `c!='\n'` is there because we want to return from the function as soon as the user has pressed the Enter key (= \n).

Comment: @yogirajput the indentation of the code is still inexistant. I'm sure this is not the way the samples are indented in the book.

Comment: @mr michael even after pressing enter(\n) it continues to take input until we press EOF.

Comment: @yogirajput please fix the indentation first, nobody wants to read this mess.

Comment: okk sure mr michael

Comment: @yogirajput and your code doesn't even compile. Did you retype your code here ??

Comment: now you can compile it mr michael...i've corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `for(i=0;i<lim-1&&(c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n';i++)`
>   why do we use `c!='\n'`

We use `c!='\n'` to stop scanning input characters when user enters a `\n` (newline) character or in other words,when user hits the `enter` key.

> why have we used `s[i]='\0'` in and  `i++;` statement in `if(c=='\n')` condition

- `i++` is used to increase the index value of the array/string for one last time to accomadate the terminating `'\0'` null character.
- `s[i]='\0'` is used to terminate\end the string with a null character. This is essential for marking the end of the string and printing  a string within bounds (upto `'\0'` character)

Comment: _This is useful while printing ..._ it's not only useful, it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: So that he can access within the bounds.right?. @MichaelWalz

Comment: _So that he can access within the bounds_ which bounds ? Access what ? In C strings are terminated by zero, period.

Comment: I meant to say if op uses printf("%s",string) without terminating string at the end with null character then he will end up getting additional characters at the end of string due to accessing out of bounds of the string

Comment: but whether we place a terminating character or not c automatically places it after any string

Comment: @yogirajput but here you are scanning each character one by one here, so it doesn't place a terminating character at the end

Comment: @yogirajput you should seriously study C from the beginning starting with very simple programs. There are tons of tutorials out there. If your program does not place a terminating NUL character at the end of the string, nobody else will do it.

Comment: @yogirajput yes, exactly.

Comment: 1 last question mr michael...though c!='\n statement is used to stop taking input but in the program if we press enter key(\n) it only changes the line but still takes input...why that so...

Comment: @yogirajput it only stops taking input into the string `s[i]` ,it doesn't end taking input from the console

Comment: okk okk mr cherubim now i got it.....thanx a ton to you and mr michael too :) you are making this world a better place

Answer (score 0):

The `getline` function is wrong.

This is the corrected readable version:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c,i;
  for(i=0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
  {
    s[i]=c;
    if(c=='\n')
    {
      s[i]='\n';
      i++;
    }
  }

  s[i]='\0';
  return i;
}
```